# Match full url in backbone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm looking for solution to invoke backbone action for particular route in my app.

I know that it's possible to match url like:

`localhost:3000/#posts/1`

But what if I need to match url like:

`localhost:3000/posts/1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opt-in to the new HTML history API / `pushState`, e.g.:

```
  Backbone.history.start( { pushState : true } );
```

Depending on your application, you may want to take other steps as well, e.g.:

> Note that using real URLs requires your web server to be able to correctly render those pages, so back-end changes are required as well.

http://backbonejs.org/#History